# NSInvalidArgumentException peristent store is not rechable from NSmanagerobjectcontext coordinator

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

Not able to understand the issue. Any help is appreciated

```
    Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9e88 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x178d8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0xd988 _PFRetainedObjectIDCore
3  CoreData                       0x600fc -[NSManagedObjectContext objectWithID:]
4  CoreData                       0x5a4c -[NSFetchedResultsController _preprocessDeletedObjects:deletesInfo:sectionsWithDeletes:]
5  CoreData                       0x5ec08 __82-[NSFetchedResultsController(PrivateMethods) _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]_block_invoke
6  CoreData                       0x837e8 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform
7  CoreData                       0x83338 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]
8  CoreData                       0x61c98 -[NSFetchedResultsController _core_managedObjectContextDidChange:]
9  CoreFoundation                 0x37404 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
10 CoreFoundation                 0xde474 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke
11 CoreFoundation                 0xc1724 _CFXRegistrationPost
12 CoreFoundation                 0x4ba08 _CFXNotificationPost
13 Foundation                     0x5cffc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
14 CoreData                       0x4cae4 -[NSManagedObjectContext _postObjectsDidChangeNotificationWithUserInfo:]
15 CoreData                       0x11f470 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _processChangedStoreConfigurationNotification:]
16 CoreData                       0x11d3d4 __95-[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _sendOrEnqueueNotification:selector:]_block_invoke
17 CoreData                       0x837e8 developerSubmittedBlockToNSManagedObjectContextPerform
18 CoreData                       0x83338 -[NSManagedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:]
19 CoreData                       0x8ed24 -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalNotificationHandling) _storeConfigurationChanged:]
20 CoreFoundation                 0x37404 __CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER__
21 CoreFoundation                 0xde474 ___CFXRegistrationPost_block_invoke
22 CoreFoundation                 0xc1724 _CFXRegistrationPost
23 CoreFoundation                 0x4ba08 _CFXNotificationPost
24 Foundation                     0x5cffc -[NSNotificationCenter postNotificationName:object:userInfo:]
25 CoreData                       0x10f3b8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _postStoresChangedNotificationsForStores:changeKey:options:]
26 CoreData                       0x12ae38 __61-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _removePersistentStore:error:]_block_invoke
27 CoreData                       0xdf840 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform
28 CoreData                       0x1935b4 _perform
29 CoreData                       0x122360 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator _removePersistentStore:error:]
30 CoreData                       0x10d914 __129-[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPrivateMethods) _destroyPersistentStoreAtURL:withType:options:error:]_block_invoke
31 CoreData                       0xdf840 gutsOfBlockToNSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPerform
32 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
33 libdispatch.dylib              0x13574 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete
34 CoreData                       0x1935a0 _perform
35 CoreData                       0x129cc8 -[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(_NSPersistentStoreCoordinatorPrivateMethods) _destroyPersistentStoreAtURL:withType:options:error:]
36 ProjectName                         0x4741dc -[CoreDataAccessBase destroyPersistentAndResetCoreDataObjects] + 234 (CoreDataAccessBase.m:234)
37 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
38 libdispatch.dylib              0x1364c _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke
39 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
40 libdispatch.dylib              0x127f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain
41 libdispatch.dylib              0x12444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
42 CoreFoundation                 0x9a6f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
43 CoreFoundation                 0x7c058 __CFRunLoopRun
44 CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
45 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal
46 UIKitCore                      0x3a23d0 -[UIApplication _run]
47 UIKitCore                      0x3a2034 UIApplicationMain
48 ProjectName                         0x3aecc main + 14 (main.m:14)
49 ???                            0x1e6344960 (Missing)
```

```
- (void) destroyPersistentAndResetCoreDataObjects
{
    @synchronized(self)
    {
        NSArray *stores = [__persistentStoreCoordinator persistentStores];
        for(NSPersistentStore *store in stores) {
            @try {
                [self.persistentStoreCoordinator destroyPersistentStoreAtURL:store.URL withType:NSSQLiteStoreType options:self.options error:nil];
            } @catch (NSException *exception) {
                VLogDebug(@"destroyPersistentAndResetCoreDataObjects%@",[exception debugDescription]);
            }
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:store.URL.path error:nil];
        }
        [self resetAllCoreDataObjects];
    }
}
```

Comment: First you call `_destroyPersistentStoreAtURL:withType:options:error` and then via a notification you get a crash in a `NSFetchedResultsController`. So maybe don't destroy the store when you have an active NSFetchedResultsController

Comment: actually we calling destroyPersistentAndResetCoreDataObjects() at the time of logout..

Comment: You still have an active NSFetchedResultsController apparently...